# How do i Indicate the form under this menu is completed

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I just wrote this code for a menu that hold several forms under it but there is a point that i want to indicate that the user has successful filled in the forms under the menu, so i want to show something like a mark icon that tell users they have finished filling the form under the menu.

See the image below:

[image]

Below are my html and css codes:

Thanks

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">


    <div id="completedStep" class="col-md-3 signUpStep">
            <div class="stepNumb">1</div>
            <div class="stepInfo">Basic Info</div>
    </div>  


    <div id="activeStep" class="col-md-3 signUpStep">
            <div class="stepNumb">2</div>
            <div class="stepInfo">Address</div>
    </div>  



    <div class="col-md-3 signUpStep">
            <div class="stepNumb">3</div>
            <div class="stepInfo">Tutoring</div>
    </div>  

    <div class="col-md-3 signUpStep">
            <div class="stepNumb">4</div>
            <div class="stepInfo">Schedule</div>
    </div>  



</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#activeStep{
background: #007ee5;
color: #fff;
}

#completedStep{
color: #888;
}

.signUpStep {
position: relative;
float: left;
background-color: #fafafa;
height: 42px;
width: 100%;
margin: 0;
overflow: hidden;
color: #007ee5;
}

.stepNumb {
float: left;
font-size: 34px;
line-height: 1em;
font-weight: 300;
}

.stepInfo {
margin-left: 28px;
line-height: 16px;
font-size: 16px;
padding-top: 5px;
}
```

Please if you can also help me review the code generally to see if it meet broswer standards, i would appreciate it.

Waiting to read from you guys.

Comment: Share you jquery or js tries? if not please try first.

Comment: Actually i want to use Css to show the icon but i would use jquery to remove and add the completedStep and activeStep classes later after figuring out how to show the above small ok icon. Thanks.

Comment: Since you're using `bootstrap` then `<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok-sign"></span>` will do the trick for you.

Comment: You know its going to be added dynamically once the current menu content have been completed and the user proceed to the next menu, so how do i achieve that with two classes?

Answer (score 0):

one way of doing this is adding a custom content image to a designated div.

```
.isValid{
  background: url("https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/glossy_ecommerce_icons/ok.png") no-repeat scroll;
  float: right;
  width: 5%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

and your HTML should be something like:

```
<div id="completedStep" class="col-md-3 signUpStep">
        <div class="isValid"></div>
        <div class="stepNumb">1</div>
        <div class="stepInfo">Basic Info</div>
</div>
```

simply add the "isValid" class to the div when its content is valid.

example: http://www.bootply.com/6UEbNL2uBQ

to show \ hide use JQuery:

```
$('#divSelector').addClass('isValid');
$('#divSelector').removeClass('isValid');
```

**EDIT:** 
if you're using bootstrap your life just became easier, make sure you read about bootstrap's form control validations at:

http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-control-validation

Comment: When i replaced the image local location with a local and live image, nothing shows up.

Comment: @Angular2Lover you can post another question on the matter with code attached so we can see whats that about. if this answer resolved your issue please don't forget to mark as resolved.